# How to align text ending with top view (ImageView) cutting text from the end?

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

Here is my code and image 
where I have carousel recyclerview and each item has quite long text
how can I cut the text and align text with the ending of imageView?

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/layout_container"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="4dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/asset_image"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        app:imageUrl="@{imageUrl}"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:layout_conversion_wrapHeight="0"
        tools:layout_conversion_wrapWidth="0" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:text="sfsdfsdfsjkfljljljljlklkjlkjkhksdjfskdjflsdjflsdjkflsjkdf"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/asset_image"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/asset_image"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/asset_image" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image: RECYCLERVIEW ITEMS]

Comment: you have to set your width to match_constraint then it will be aligned to your imageview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

1.Set text view width to match constraints (0dp)

2.Set constraints of the TextView`s right/letf to ImageView's right / left

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            tools:src="@tools:sample/avatars"
            android:layout_height="250dp"   
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/texts"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            tools:text="@tools:sample/lorem/random"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/imageView"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/imageView"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to give your `textview width = "match_constraint"` which is basically equal to `0dp` this way your `textview` `width` will be equal to the constraint you have set at the end of your `textview`:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_title"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:text="sfsdfsdfsjkfljljljljlklkjlkjkhksdjfskdjflsdjflsdjkflsjkdf"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/asset_image"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/asset_image"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/asset_image" />
```

Answer (score -2):

Just change `android:layout_width="wrap_content"` to `android:layout_width="120dp"`

Comment: What if he wants to change the imageviews size in the future?

Comment: then change the text view as well? it works right? maybe not the best solution, but is not wrong

Comment: well its correct, but something if works that not means is the way to do it.

Comment: Well he chooses the solution that he wants, there is nothing wrong with my answer